# What does CTP stand for in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am seeing CTP in an awful lot of posts lately.  What does CTP stand for ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**C**ommunity **T**echnology **P**review.

It's a kind of public beta.

Answer (score 0):

Community Technology Preview. When something is released for testing, often free and not quite beta.